# For security reasons framing is not allowed

Tags: bug, support

Whenever I follow an outside link on ux.stackchange and then use the back button to return, I get a alert about iframes.

I looked at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265627/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-on, but since this doesn’t happen from other sites (stack overflow, workplace) even if going to the same domain (Wikipedia for instance), I thought I’d mention it.

This is a page I just had this problem with:
  [Are there names for patterns within UI styles?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36493/are-there-names-for-patterns-within-ui-styles).
And this one:
   [If I need to show a list of http methods for selection, is there a recommended order in which to display them?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/104537/if-i-need-to-show-a-list-of-http-methods-for-selection-is-there-a-recommended-o)

Comment: I haven't seen this before. What other details can you provide? Which browser 
and version are you using? Do all UX pages do this, or perhaps only on some (e.g. question pages only)? Do you have any plugins or extensions in your browser? If so, can you replicate the issue with these disabled?

Comment: @maxathousand: I’m using an iPad, ios11.4.1, Safari, and I have only followed links from answers and comments. I just tried all of the links on the footer of the home page, no alerts.  The various SE links seem to be OK. Weirdly, I was trying to test in another tab while writing this, and it seemed like it was working and then I got the error for going back WITHIN ux... no plugins or extensions